# Django Rest filtering via query params

Tags: python, django, rest, filtering, django-rest-framework

I am filtering by query params to find the user that matches the phone number in the query params.

Model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/user_images', blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)
    notifications = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    group_notifications = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    payment_info = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="PLACEHOLDER TEXT")
```

View:

```
class UsersList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
         queryset = User.objects.all()
         phone_number = self.request.query_params.get('phone_number', None)
        if phone_number is not None:
             queryset = queryset.filter(userprofile_phone_number=phone_number)
        return queryset
```

Urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from users import views

urlpatterns = [

     url(r'find$', views.UsersList.as_view()),

]
```

and this is the error I get when entering this: http://localhost:9000/find?phone_number=+447865940489

```
 FieldError at /api/v1/user/find
Cannot resolve keyword 'userprofile_phone_number' into field. Choices are: auth_token, date_joined, email, emailaddress, event, eventmembersattending, first_name, groupmember, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, request, socialaccount, suggestion, tags, user_permissions, username, userprofile
```

So what have I done wrong?

EDIT: Error solved but now I get an empty response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **use double underscores** to access the `phone_number` field of the related `userprofile` field.

From Django docs on [lookups that span relationships:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

> To span a relationship, just use the field name of related fields
>   across models, **separated by double underscores**, until you get to the
>   field you want.

Change the following line in `get_queryset()`

```
queryset = queryset.filter(userprofile_phone_number=phone_number) # wrong
```

to

```
queryset = queryset.filter(userprofile__phone_number=phone_number) # use double underscores
```

Comment: Thanks that got rid of the error, but now I get an empty response?

Comment: Maybe because there are no users with that value of `phone_number` in the db. Check if the queryset returns some object with that filter or a `[]`.

Comment: Tried with phone numbers that are in the db and still get []

Comment: Check if the query is made with `phone_number` in proper format and type.

Comment: I solved it, in the database the phone numbers are saved with the + but in the query params it needed to be %2B